# Variable required can't assign to this expression with parentheses

Tags: vba, excel

I'm developing a macro with VBA and for some reason, I need to add parentheses to my variable when I call a function.
I do that to make my code cross-platform with the VBA on Mac and the data exchange with c++ libraries.

I have a sample of code which reproduces the error.

```
    Private Type S0
        x As Double
    End Type

    Private Type S1
        s_0 As S0
    End Type

    Private Type S2
        s_1() As S1
    End Type

    Private Sub RunMe()
        Dim l As S2
        ReDim l.s_1(1 To 2)

        'no error
        Call Display(l.s_1(1).s_0)

        'compilation error : variable required can't assign to this expression
        Call Display((l.s_1(1).s_0))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Display(d As S0)
        MsgBox d.x
    End Sub
```

As you can see, it's not logical to call my function Display with additionals parentheses but I don't know why, it's work like this for basic cases.

If I use only basic types, it works. I think it's related to the user define type.

So, I have two questions:

- What is the VBA comportment when I add parentheses like in my example?
- What can I do to avoid the compil error and keep the same comportment?

Thank you very much to read me and to help me!

Comment: To your first question: see my answer. To your second question: simply don't put the parentheses around. Why do you think you need them?

Comment: On Mac, if I call a C++ function from a library after the Display Call, I can't retrieve the array s_1. I only have a null pointer to the data memory address (SAFEARRAY* type and pvData). 
It's work well under PC because a VBA array is a SAFEARRAY and it is native (Windows Framework) and easy to use on C++.
But on Mac, I have to redefine this structure in my C++ and it's work well except when I pass a subpart of my array to a function before my c++ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default variable passing method in `VBA` is `ByRef`. But "Even if a called procedure has declared its parameters as ByRef, you can force those to be ByVal by enclosing each argument within parentheses." see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx.

So your `Call Display((l.s_1(1).s_0))` tries passing the `(l.s_1(1).s_0)` as user defined type `S0` `ByVal`.

But [User-defined type may not be passed ByVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/user-defined-type-may-not-be-passed-byval). Thats why the error.

Comment: Thank you. I understand well what is going back the parenthesis.
So, I need to find a workaround for my case.
Best